# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str' in logistic regression model

Tags: python, database, logistic-regression

I want to classify malicious urls as good or bad using machine learning in python and everything going okay but this error appears. The code below is used to model the dataset and the last thing was writing is the problem. moreover I write down the full Traceback error , I tried to remove all null values but noting work

```
      [# EDA Packages

        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        import random

    # Machine Learning Packages
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    # Load Url Data 
    urls_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/iot/data/dataot.csv',error_bad_lines=False, encoding = 'unicode_escape')

    type(urls_data)

    urls_data.head()

    def makeTokens(f):
        tkns_BySlash = str(f.encode('utf-8')).split('/')    # make tokens after splitting by slash
        total_Tokens = \[\]
        for i in tkns_BySlash:
            tokens = str(i).split('-')  # make tokens after splitting by dash
            tkns_ByDot = \[\]
            for j in range(0,len(tokens)):
                temp_Tokens = str(tokens\[j\]).split('.')   # make tokens after splitting by dot
                tkns_ByDot = tkns_ByDot + temp_Tokens
            total_Tokens = total_Tokens + tokens + tkns_ByDot
        total_Tokens = list(set(total_Tokens))  #remove redundant tokens
        if 'com' in total_Tokens:
            total_Tokens.remove('com')  #removing .com since it occurs a lot of times and it should not be included in our features
        return total_Tokens

    # Labels
    y = urls_data\["label"\]

    # Features
    url_list = urls_data\["url"\]

    # Using Default Tokenizer
    #vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

    # Using Custom Tokenizer
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=makeTokens)

    # Store vectors into X variable as Our XFeatures
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(url_list)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    # Model Building
    #using logistic regression
    logit = LogisticRegression()    
    logit.fit(X_train, y_train, errors='coerce')]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-73b6ea97c396> in <module>
      2 #using logistic regression
      3 logit = LogisticRegression()
----> 4 logit.fit(X_train, y_train)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1284         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype, order="C",
   1285                          accept_large_sparse=solver != 'liblinear')
-> 1286         check_classification_targets(y)
   1287         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
   1288         n_samples, n_features = X.shape

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    166     y : array-like
    167     """
--> 168     y_type = type_of_target(y)
    169     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    170                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
    285         return 'continuous' + suffix
    286 
--> 287     if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
    288         return 'multiclass' + suffix  # [1, 2, 3] or [[1., 2., 3]] or [[1, 2]]
    289     else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    231     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    232     if axis is None:
--> 233         ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    234         return _unpack_tuple(ret)
    235 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    279         aux = ar[perm]
    280     else:
--> 281         ar.sort()
    282         aux = ar
    283     mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please update the question with the Full Error Traceback.

Comment: Btw. you fit the tf-idf vectors on the data that you leave out for testing. This won't get you a reliable test-time estimate because the "real unseen" URLs were not included in your tf-idf training.

Comment: @quamrana 36 I edit it